# HP ENVY 5530 not working after ugrade to 22.04

Tags: 22.04, printing, hp

Last week I upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04.1. Ever since I have been unable to print anything on my HP ENVY 5530, which was working perfectly on 20.04.

I am able to install the printer both using `hp-setup` and in the back-end using CUPS. However when I go to actually print something I get the error:

> Printer Error Error Connecting to Device

How can I solve this?

Comment: use a usb with _Try Ubuntu_ turn the printer on after it has loaded and see if that works as part of the process in investigating the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Execute `driverless`. This gives you a URI. Substitute in `lpadmin -p Envy5530 -v "URI" -E -m everywhere` and print to Envy5530.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution with the following steps:

1. Remove some packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove libhpmud0 libsane-hpaio printer-driver-postscript-hp
   ```
2. Download the latest version of `hplip` (currently `hplip-3.23.3.run`) from here: https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip
3. From within the directory that you downloaded `hplip-3.23.3.run` (adjust for the downloaded version), run the following command to give it execution permissions:

   ```
   chmod u+x hplip-3.23.3.run
   ```
4. Install the package:

   ```
   ./hplip-3.23.3.run
   ```